# eglsurface is destroyed when entering an activity with no theme

Tags: android, surfaceview, egl

So basically I have an app that does some open gl rendering but also some activities the user enters to set some things up.

Curious thing, but if I enter in an activity that doesn't have the following attribute

android:theme="@style/ThemeDialog"

where ThemeDialog is basically a style that has the parent attribute set to

@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"

the surface view is destroyed. 
How on earth are one related to the other? I can't seem to find a rational explanation.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The default theme uses an opaque window. This means that when you open an `Activity` without a theme specified in the manifest it hides the current `Activity` that contains your `SurfaceView`. When an `Activity` is hidden the system is free to reclaim the surface. The surface is recreated when you go back to your original `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have activities A B C D and E.

A B C D - all have the same theme, Theme.Holo.Dialog
E - doesn't have any theme specified (so the default, opaque one)

A - this activity holds the surface that I draw on

If I open A, then B (over A), then C (over B), then D (over C), the surface is OK.

If I open A, then B (over A), then C (over B), then E (over C), the following happens:
1. when switching from C to E, the surface is destroyed
and
2. when going back from E to C, the surface is restored (surface changed event)

As you can see, A is far behind this sequence of activities. So what does A's surface got to do with the fact that E has no theme? Why is A'surface being destroyed when switching from a themable activity (C) to a non themable one (E)?